# How to detect color in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to make a program that take input (colored paper) from a Webcam, and the output is string of that color of the paper. For example, if I hold a blue paper in front of my webcam it's going to tell me "blue".

Answer (score 2):

Use [PIL](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm) library if open cv is not a neccessity for you.
Here is a function that open an image and look for the main color.

```
import urllib2
import ImageFile

image_url = "/path of the file"
opener1 = urllib2.build_opener()
page1=opener1.open(image_url)

p = ImageFile.Parser()

while 1:
    s = page1.read(1024)
    if not s:
        break
    p.feed(s)

im = p.close()
r,g,b = im.getpixel((0,0))
```

From RGB values you can decide what is the color.
I hope it helps..

EDIT:You can also use its [getcolors() function](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm).
im.getcolors(maxcolors) ⇒ a list of (count, color) tuples or None

It returns an unsorted list of (count, color) tuples, where count is the number of times the corresponding color occurs in the image.